# MAXIMUM AND VALUE

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

Given a positive integer N , and a range of positive integers from L to R . Find the smallest positive integer in the range having Maximum Bitwise AND value with N.

NOTE: N needn't to be necessarily lie in the range L to R.

Comment: Is this a home assignment? What have you tried so far?

Comment: lmao why'd you just wanna figure this particular thing out, yes @MaximKosov this is a part of an ongoing contest. Best would be to figure yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume the answer for now to be zero `0`. Take the binary representation of N. Go from Most significant bit (MSB) to Least Significant bit (LSB), one by one. If you get a `0`, skip. If you get a `1`, bitwise OR it with the answer (keeping `1` at the same position) and see if answer is in the range from L to R. If `Answer` is less than equal to `R` (assuming the `R` to be inclusive), keep the bit as `1` (even if it is less than `L`). If `Answer` is greater than `R`, revert the bit to `0` and go to next bit in `N`.

**Example 1:**
`N` = 10 decimal, `1010` binary.
`L` = 5.
`R` = 15.
`Answer` = 0.
We start from the MSB `1` of `N`.

`Answer` OR `1000`= 1000 binary is between `L` and `R`. We keep it and move to next bit in `N`.

Next bit is `0`. We do nothing and go to next bit.

Next bit is `1`. `Answer` OR `0010` = `1010`, which is between `L` and `R`. We keep it and go ahead.

Next bit is `0`. We do nothing. We are at the end of `N`. We have our answer.

`Answer` = `1010`.

**Example 2**: N = 45 (`101101`), L = 32, R = 36.

`Answer` OR `100000` = `100000` which is 32, between `L` and `R`. We keep it as `1` and proceed.

`Answer` OR `1000` = `101000` which is 40. Greater than `R`. We revert answer to `100000` and proceed.

`Answer` OR `100` = `100100` which is 36. Which is `R`. Another optimization: we can stop here since OR-ing  anything with `Answer` will now increase its value beyond `R`.

Some more optimizations can be done, like if `N` and `R` are equal, `R` should be the answer.

In some cases, the answer might come as `0` (Ex. `N` = 45, `L` = 16, `R` = 16). Can take `L` as the answer depending on the specification of the question.

Comment: But will it be smallest ?

Comment: Other than the answer above, AND-ing `11`, `14` and `15` with `N` would give you max value of `10`. Since we are not setting the bits on the position where `N` has a `0`, we are not increasing the value of answer unnecessarily. Like we can put a `1` at second step also to get the max bitwise value AND with N, but that is going to be AND-ed (if that is word?) with the `0` in `N`. We are avoiding that.